# Fancybox add image to gallery

Tags: fancybox, image-gallery

I'm working on a site, where I have 3 images of an item displayed, but there are can be more than 3 images of an item. I want to use fancybox to display them, but I couldn't figure out how it could be done.

I know how to create a gallery "manually", but I don't know how to add images manually to an existing gallery which is identified by a class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there are any methods in Fancybox for programatically adding an image to a gallery.  Perhaps you could contact the author and request it, or you could modify the script.

Comment: I just set display to none on the other images and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recreate the fancybox gallery each time you add a new image.  As simshaun said, there is no method for adding new images to an existing fancybox gallery.

From the [Fancybox example page](http://fancybox.net/howto), you need to have the same `ref` parameter on each image in order to create the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: none;"> <a class="fancybox-effects-c"
href="images/test.jpg" data-fancybox-group="groupname" ><img
src="test.jpg"  alt="" /></a> </div>
```

This should work as the image will be there and added to the fancybox but just not shown.